# Extension configuration with multiple Visual Studios

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I have both visual studio 2012 and 2017 installed but QT VS 2017 extension tries to install to Visual Studio 2012 instead of 2017. In the log, when searching for products it founds Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 instead of 2017

Comment: Hi, does the extension means "QT Visual Studio Tools", which is an add-in in visual studio for vs. If so, please make sure 1.The VS2017 is installed in default path and 2.In vs2017, Go Tools menu=>Extensions and Updates=>Search "qt" in online node, download and install it to check if it helps

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT yes QT Visual Studio tools. Sadly, I cant search online because my work computer has no access to internet. And can you say where does the path goes to? I mean its installed in C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community do I have to give a bin folder or something or is this enough?

Comment: The path seems right. And after my test with different machine, it seems something wrong with your vsix file. What's the name of your extension name?

Comment: Friend, any update please feel free to share here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An add-in for vs2017 won't search for vs2012, unless it's an add-in
> for vs2012.

Senario: A remote machine with VS2010,2012,2015,2017(community and enterprise)

I start the vsix(2017), and the pic shows below:
[image]

It won't search for other versions of vs since it's specified for vs2017.

> Steps to figure it out:

1.Download the tool from [this page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools-19123).The file name should be `qt-vsaddin-msvc2017-2.3.2.vsix`(If you have downloaded it before, please re-download)

2.If the new vsix still searchs for vs2012, please repair your vs by Control panel=>Programs=>Programs and features=>right-click vs, change=>repair. Also, since it works well for my VS community 15.9.7, please update your vs to 15.9.7 or higher.

Comment: yeah I tried to run that exact tool but still it tried to go for vs2012. Repairing also didnt work so I removed vs 2012, then it worked as intended

Comment: Do you mean remove vs2012, then the vsix could work well?

Comment: @DevelopmentPeasant If so, I suggest you can add it as answer. Though it's a simple way, but most time a simple uninstall or reinstall of vs works more efficiently than long time for trouble-shooting.